# FlowCover problem objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, coverflow

I'm trying to make use of FlowCover -> http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m but it is not working.

This is my interface class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FlowCoverView.h"

@interface TesterCoverFlowViewController : UIViewController <FlowCoverViewDelegate> {

}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

This is my implementation class:

```
#import "TesterCoverFlowViewController.h"

@implementation TesterCoverFlowViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
   (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
}


- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
 [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

/************************************************************************/
/*                  */
/* FlowCover Callbacks             */
/*                  */
/************************************************************************/

- (int)flowCoverNumberImages:(FlowCoverView *)view
{
 return 64;
}

- (UIImage *)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view cover:(int)image
{
 switch (image % 6) {
  case 0:
  default:
   return [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
  case 1:
   return [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
  case 2:
   return [UIImage imageNamed:@"c.png"];
  case 3:
   return [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];
  case 4:
   return [UIImage imageNamed:@"y.png"];
  case 5:
   return [UIImage imageNamed:@"z.png"];
 }
}

- (void)flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view didSelect:(int)image
{
 NSLog(@"Selected Index %d",image);
}


@end
```

Most of the code is taken from the site.

Do I need to do anything to the interface? Because nothing appears! no errors, I just don't see any coverflow (or flowcover).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not seeing any errors than it is more than likely a missing delegate or the view is not being presented.

Are you showing that `UIViewController` with something like `presentModalViewController`?

Did you assign the `TesterCoverFlowViewController` class as the delegate of the `FlowCoverView`?

Comment: The project is a view controller project so that stuff should be created automatically. And the view is definitely appearing since when i change  its colour , this change is apparently when i run the application but hte coverflow doesnt show :S

Comment: Are your delegate methods being called?